# Higher order moments and shape parameters

Tags: matlab, distribution, kurtosis

I have used 5th moment of my data as a feature for classification and it gives good results, but i don't know what it measures? is it a shape parameter like kurtosis and skewness?
I'm using matlab's

```
m=moment(X,order);
```

which returns the central sample moment of *X* specified by the positive integer *order*.

Comment: How are you defining the 5th moment? As the expected value of X to the 5th power, as a moment about the mean, or in some other way? I'm thinking that it will act in concert with the skewness - if skewness is negative, so will your 5th moment be negative. If skewness is positive, so will your 5th moment be postive.

Comment: I've edited my question. we say that skewness measures the asymmetry of distribution but what about 5th moment since it provides such good results.